# How to design screen React native for IOS?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have a sample image. I want to design screen in IOS as per Image layout.
[image: give image is a screen layout]

I want it in react-native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, you should be able to understand the basics of flex styles.
Small list of tutorials in no particular order:

- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html
- https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/get-started-with-layouts-in-react-native--cms-27418
- http://www.reactnativeexpress.com/flexbox

Really, you don't need much else, only exercise.

However, if you're not looking for propositive ideas to enhance your react-native understanding, but you just need somebody who can get the work done, I would suggest you either a freelance developer, or some serius guys in the react-native world such as the ones at [Callstack](https://callstack.io/#contact) or [Geeky Ants](http://geekyants.com/#contact).

Stackoverflow is a great place for asking help with hideous bugs of which the whole community may benefit, but [it just isn't a place where to ask somebody to do the hard work for you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) :)